# Tap Count & Lap

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, tap

I created sample tap count app. But I don't know how to count lap. Example: when hit count 100, lap is 1. when hit count 200 lap is 2. I used following code. Thanks. I am xcode beginner.

Following Code is ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)plus {
    counter=counter +1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter];
}

-(IBAction)minus {
     counter=counter -1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter];
 }

 -(IBAction)zero {
     counter=0;
     count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    counter=0;
     count.text=@"0";
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 @end
```

Following Code is ViewController.h
     #import

```
 int counter;

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController {
     IBOutlet UILabel *count;
     IBOutlet UILabel *lap;
 }

 -(IBAction)plus;
 -(IBAction)minus;
 -(IBAction)zero;
 @end
```

Comment: Not sure, what the question but looks like you do have every thing you need in your code. Can you be more specific of what you want to do. Is the above code working, or do you want some thing additional to be done which you are not clear about.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, this code is work but I need some additional. Example: when hit count 100, lap is 1. when hit count 200 lap is 2. I used following code. Thanks. I am xcode beginner.

Comment: Not sure if your lap value can change or not depending on the value of counter, but either wise, all you would need to do is after counter=counter+1, counter=counter-1 and counter=0, put the following line "lap.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:%i",counter/100];" This does integer division and will give you the correct answer

Comment: I answered the question, note that this question is NOT related to Xcode. Instead, it should be put under objective-c, iOS is fine (Although Cocoa-Touch is preferred, perhaps both), and tap is good. I added math, because that seems to really be about what this is about. Logic would work here too. Never be afraid to have to many tags, as long as they apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I accomplished this. Now note that I am not using your exact set up, but this should work, or at least give you the right idea. This should in theory be a lot harder, as you really want to check the lap for an infinite amounts of 100's, so we need some logic too check, EXCEPT if we use int. Int is not precise, so if we take say 50/100, it will still return 0. However, 100/100 = 1, 200/100 = 2, 275/100 still equals 2. This will accomplish what you want easily.

Here's a simple example with only a button that increments the amount, I use global variables for lap count and tap count.

In the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TapCounterViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender;

@end
```

In the .m

```
#import "TapCounterViewController.h"

@interface TapCounterViewController ()

@end

@implementation TapCounterViewController

int lapNumber = 0;
int buttonTaps = 0;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    buttonTaps = buttonTaps + 1;
    NSLog(@"Current Button Taps = %i", buttonTaps);

    //Check for Lap
    [self checkForLap];
}


-(void)checkForLap {
    //We must divide by 100 to check for the number if laps.
    int laps = buttonTaps/100;
    NSLog(@"Number of laps = %i", laps);
    lapNumber = laps;
}
@end
```

This can be easily adapted for decrementing, resetting you whatever. Just whenever you make a change to button tap, execute checkForLap.

Good luck, and if you need more info let me know!

EDIT

As for the vibration:

There are two seemingly similar functions that take a parameter kSystemSoundID_Vibrate:

1) `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`
2) `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

Both the functions vibrate the iPhone. But when you use the first function on devices that don’t support vibration, it plays a beep sound. The second function on the other hand does nothing on unsupported devices. So if you are going to vibrate the device continuously, as a alert, common sense says, use function 2.

See also "iPhone Tutorial: Better way to check capabilities of iOS devices" article.

Header files to import:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Comment: Note: If you want more precise lap count use something like float instead of int.

Comment: I have one more question. How can I vibrate for every lap?